# jQuery SlideToggle doesn't work on elements that are not semantically adjacent

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, api

I'm using the amazing `slideToggle();` function from the jQuery API.  The issue I'm encountering is that I thought I could target the next `.slide_toggle_container` by using the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
    $(".toggle_container").hide(); 

    //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });

}); // End of document.ready
```

The problem is that the above code works great with the following HTML

```
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eget venenatis turpis. Fusce et ante diam, venenatis vestibulum tortor. Nam ultrices accumsan velit sit amet sagittis.</p>

            <a class="trigger toggle" href="#">Read More</a>

            <div class="toggle_container">Sliding Content</div>
```

But for styling purposes, I need to use the following HTML, which causes the `.trigger` and `slideToggle` to not work.

```
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eget venenatis turpis. Fusce et ante diam, venenatis vestibulum tortor. Nam ultrices accumsan velit sit amet sagittis.<a class="trigger toggle" href="#">Read More</a></p>

            <div class="toggle_container">Sliding Content</div>
```

My understanding from some research is that the HTML above (2nd) does not work because the `.trigger` is contained within `<p>` and the `slide_toggle_container` is not recognized as the `.next()` element in the DOM.  Any help?  How can I make this work with the second HTML scenario above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parent()` method to access the parent of the anchor and then call next to access the div.

Change:

```
 $(this).toggleClass("active").next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
```

to

```
 $(this).toggleClass("active").parent().next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
    $(".toggle_container").hide(); 

    //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active").closest("p").next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
        return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });

}); // End of document.ready
```